# generar una tarea asincrona y retornar vista sin esperarla .net

Tags: c#, .net, hilos

estoy queriendo realizar un metodo asincrono pero tengo el problema que, si bien lo realiza de manera asincrona, no retorna el valor hasta que este no termina. Yo necesito que retorne la vista y continue aunque la tarea no haya finalizado

```
        Thread oThread = new Thread(ProtocolizacionS.ActualizarProtocolizados);

        oThread.IsBackground = true;

        //// Start the thread
        oThread.Start();
        //while (!oThread.IsAlive) ;


        var devuelta = Proyecto.ListadoVista(user.Login, programaCodigo, expedienteNro, expedienteAno, beneficiario, estadoCodigo, titulo);


        return Json(devuelta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: usas winforms?? o wpf?

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, puedes utilizar el Task.Yield() que sería de la siguiente forma (asumiendo que se hace con el evento clic de un botón):

```
async void boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      await Task.Yield(); // Esto hace que se procese en segundo planoMake us async right away

      return Proyecto.ListadoVista(user.Login, programaCodigo, expedienteNro, expedienteAno, beneficiario, estadoCodigo, titulo);
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo voy a probar y despues te cuento

Comment: @NicolásKuglien, que tal te fue? funcionó como esperabas?